# Mod rewrite won't work with slashes in rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

Stack,

I have been pulling my hair out today and yesterday trying to figure out the issue I have with mod_rewrite.

I'm running an ubuntu lamp server and I've gotten mod_rewrite turned on and working for simple rewrites such as:

```
RewriteRule ^link([^/]*).html$ rewrite.php?link=$1 [L]
```

But whenever I try to rewrite urls to turn my dynamic urls into cleaner static looking urls IE:

`random/5000/` to `random.php?id=5000`

mod rewrite fails to rewrite the variable.  However if I create this following rule it works:

`random5000.html` to `random.php?id=5000`

It looks like mod rewrite is simply not accepting slashes in my rewrite rules.

Here is what my rewrite rule looks like.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^random/([0-9]+)$ random.php?id=$1
```

Comment: What exactly means 'fails to rewrite'? What happens, and what is the expected outcome? Does the url change? Does the page show or does it give an error? Etc.

Comment: @StephanMuller It goes to the random.php file but I can't "get" the id variable from the rewritten url. It's as if I'm just going to mydomain.com/random.php instead of mydomain.com/random.php?id=50 whenever I type the url mydomain.com/random/50/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but maybe your `RewriteRule` should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^random/([0-9]+)/$ random.php?id=$1
```

(missing `/` at the end). Please add comment if it fails.